# How do i access the results array to get a specific value in the objects returned

Tags: ansible

I am having trouble accessing some values in a results array returned by ansible, when I debug the variable I registered from command module.

I am running multiple commands using with_items and register the result in a "registeredVar". I tried to access the results like this `registeredVar.results.stdout` but I get "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!" error.

I also tried to loop through the results array in the debug task, but i get a "object' has no attribute 'stdout'" error

Below are the tasks I am running

```
- name: check configuration
  shell: "{{ item }}"
  register: falcon_config
  with_items:
    - /opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -g --aph
    - /opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -g --cid
    - /opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -g --app
```

Below is the debug task to output the variable

```
- debug:
    var: falcon_config['results'].stdout
```

alternativley:

```
- debug:
    var: '{{ item.stdout }}'
  with_items: falcon_config['results']
```

This is the debug output of the results array when run `falcon_config['results']`

```
    "falcon_config['results']": [
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "/opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -g --aph",
            "delta": "0:00:00.006724",
            "end": "2019-07-29 10:36:05.481672",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "/opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -g --aph",
                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": "/opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -g --aph",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2019-07-29 10:36:05.474948",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "aph=crowdstrike.domain.",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "aph=crowdstrike.intra.absaafrica."
            ]
        },
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "/opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -g --cid",
            "delta": "0:00:00.006716",
            "end": "2019-07-29 10:36:05.662173",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "/opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -g --cid",
                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": "/opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -g --cid",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2019-07-29 10:36:05.655457",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "cid=\"185d26e78791sksdasd9d1033sa4\".",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "cid=\"185d26e78791sksdasd9d1033sa4\"."
            ]
        },
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "/opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -g --app",
            "delta": "0:00:00.006617",
            "end": "2019-07-29 10:36:05.840573",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "/opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -g --app",
                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": "/opt/CrowdStrike/falconctl -g --app",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2019-07-29 10:36:05.833956",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "app=8080.",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "app=8080."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I cant get the stdout value of each object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `json_query` filter:

```
    - debug:
        var: falcon_config | json_query('results[*].stdout')
```

This will also work as input to a loop

Comment: When running through a loop it is best to define the key within the debug e.g.
`- debug: 
    msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
  loop: "{{ falcon_config | json_query('results[*]') }}"`

Comment: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "You need to install \"jmespath\" prior to running json_query filter"}

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that when you `register` the output of a module on a loop, you end up with a list. So, on the line `var: falcon_config['results'].stdout` it fails because `falcon_config['results']` is a list and doesn't have a `stdoud` key. You have to access this result inside a loop.

Ths snippet you've included should work:

```
- debug:
    var: '{{ item.stdout }}'
  with_items: falcon_config['results']
```

I tested your code with the following `playbook`, and it does:

```
---
- hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Run all shell commands
      shell: '{{ item }}'
      register: falcon_config
      with_items:
        - 'echo Hello World'
        - 'echo Something'
        - 'echo lorem ipsum'

    - name: Debug the results
      debug:
        var: item["stdout"]
      with_items: '{{ falcon_config["results"] }}'
```

I hope it helps